# Angular Js File Upload

Tags: jquery, django, angularjs

i am new to angular js. i want to upload file using this.
i used following link

http://jsfiddle.net/jasonals/WEvwz/27/?
upload.html

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
<div ng-controller='TestCtrl'>
  <div>
      <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" data-url="/" multiple>
      <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="file in fileList">
              {{file.name}}
          </li>
      </ul>
  </div>

  <button ng-click='addButtonClicked()'>Add File</button>
</div>

controlller file.
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        dataType: 'json'});
});

TestCtrl = function($scope){
    $scope.fileList = [];
    $('#fileupload').bind('fileuploadadd', function(e, data){
        // Add the files to the list
        numFiles = $scope.fileList.length
        for (var i=0; i < data.files.length; ++i) {
            var file = data.files[i];
        // .$apply to update angular when something else makes changes
        $scope.$apply(
            $scope.fileList.push({name: file.name})
            );
        }
        // Begin upload immediately
        data.submit();
    });
    $scope.addButtonClicked = function(){
        var numFiles = $scope.fileList.length;
        $scope.fileList.push({name: ('fileName' + numFiles)});
    }
}
```

but i am unable to post the url using this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        dataType: 'json'});
});

TestCtrl = function($scope){
    $scope.fileList = [];
    $('#fileupload').bind('fileuploadadd', function(e, data){
            $scope.$apply(
            $scope.fileList.push({name: file.name})
            );   
        data.submit();
    });

}
```

Answer (score 5):

I can't answer your question directly, except to say: make sure you have the `data-url` set on your input from the example on JSFiddle.

As an alternative, I would recommend [angular-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload) which I've used with success. It uses angular directives to accomplish the uploading. This pattern uses a little more code, but separates the concerns in your application so you Controller just glues things together, and your service actually talks to the outside world.

This will make your app easier to test:

```
<div ng-controller="FileUploadController">
  <h3>Upload a file</h3>
  <input type="file" ng-file-select="uploadFile($files)" />
</div>
```

And the javascript:

```
// define the app, include the file upload dependency
var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['ng', 'angularFileUpload']);

// controller to handle the file upload event
app.controller('FileUploadController', 
  function ($scope, $rootScope, FileUploadService) {
    var service = FileUploadService;
    /** 
     *  Handler to upload a new file to the server.
     */
    $scope.uploadFile = function ($files) {
      var $file = $files[0];
      service.uploadFile($file, function (error) {
        if (error) {
          alert('There was a problem uploading the file.');
        }
        // handle successfully-uploaded file
      })
    }
  });

// services should interact with the outside world
app.factory('FileUploadService', function ($http) {
  var api = {
    uploadFile: function (file, callback) {
      $http.uploadFile({
        url: '/some/remote/end/point/',
        file: file
      }).progress(function(event) {
        console.log('percent: ' + parseInt(100.0 * event.loaded / event.total));
      }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        console.error('Error uploading file')
        callback(status);
      }).then(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        callback(null);
      });
    }
  }
  return api;
});
```

Comment: thanks . here is what i actually want. really it's working proper. thanks for help.